# Azure with SSL issue

Tags: iis, ssl, https, azure, ssl-certificate

I just bought a SSL Certificate for an parked domain that im going to use for redricting users to my azure web service. The problem is that when i redrict the user to the azure webservice the certificate isn't valid for that page, i guess it's becuase it was issued to my parked domain. But the only reason why i issued it for my parked domain was because it isn't possible to register a SSL certificate for an azure webservice because when you are registering your certificate you have to validate your domain and therefor need access too email adresses that are presented by the SSL manifactor. And the email that the manifactors present are those emails that only Microsoft have acess too.

**So, this what i want it to be like (not real adresses):**

User visit **www.helloworld.net** ---> User are connected to **www.helloworld.net** using a valid SSL Certificate ---> User gets immediately redricted to **helloworld.cloudapp.net** ---> User are connected to **helloworld.cloudapp.net** using the same SSL Certificate

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this work you shouldn't use redirect, but use CNAME instead.

Resources:

- http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2012/04/15/how-to-request-buy-a-certificate-and-use-it-in-windows-azure-comment-demander-acheter-un-certificat-et-l-utiliser-dans-windows-azure.aspx